# PhantomJS or CasperJS form autosubmit

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am building a laboratory task for exploitation CSRF vulnerability.
I need a bot, who will visit my page and execute JS:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:9010/csrf/register.php" method="POST" id="csrf-form">
      <input type="hidden" name="login" value="casper" />
      <input type="hidden" name="password" value="casper" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request"/>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>document.getElementById("csrf-form").submit()</script>
</html>
```

I can't proceed it with PhantomJS or CasperJS.
I don't know how HTML code will look like for different students (form id attribute can be different), I just want to execute JS code on page.
CasperJS version 1.1.4 at /opt/casperjs, using phantomjs version 2.1.1

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://127.0.0.1/mypage.html');
```

Comment: What is your PhantomJS version? Can you show your script? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: CasperJS version 1.1.4 at /opt/casperjs, using phantomjs version 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know the form `id` attribute (and since other element attributes are specific to each student), you can use [`casper.fillXPath()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillxpath) to use general selectors to fill out and auto-submit your form.

**Example:**

```
casper.start('https://example.com/', function () {
  this.fillXPath('form', {
    '//form/input[@type="hidden"][1]': username,
    '//form/input[@type="hidden"][2]': password,
  }, true);
});
```

Otherwise, you can look into using [`casper.fill()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill), [`casper.fillSelectors()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors), or [`casper.fillLabels()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#filllabels) if you know more information about the selectors being used in the form.

If you need to simply execute JavaScript into the Page DOM environment, you can use [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).